# How to make table not be resized?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I prevent a table from being resized?

I change the content of the table with Ajax so I want the table to be fixed, not resized automatically as the content changes.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `width` attribute on your table cells to fix their width.

You only have to use it on cells in the first row of your table; the browser will keep those widths for all the cells in the respective columns.

Alternatively, you can add a `class` attribute to your table cells, and set their width i your stylesheet. If so, you might want to also apply `table-layout: fixed` to your `<table>` tag.

Comment: @Dampe: eyup. I tend to stick with HTML for this one, because to do it via CSS you have to add a class anyway (so why not add the width attribute), and it’s one of those attributes that seems easier to keep track of when it‘s in the HTML. That said, if you’ve got a class on the table cells anyway, then it’s probably better to keep everything in the CSS.

Comment: Indeed.. it's situation dependant :)

Comment: @Buffon: oh, okay. Sorry about that. Could you elaborate? Maybe pop up a JSFiddle of the code you’re trying?

Answer (score 1):

Do it with CSS:

```
table td {
  width: [somevalue];
  height: [somevalue];
}
```

That way the cells will remain the same size even when the content is changed.

Answer (score 1):

I have [this suggestion](http://jsfiddle.net/MNPGV/) please check it out. I'm not that good in css but I just thought that maybe a work-around would help. :)